# ios simulator always loading or stuck black screen

Tags: ios, xcode, simulator

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/otv42.png)When I run my app on the simulator, after i update new macos somona and xcode 15, my ios simulator stuck loading or black screen i am downlaoding ios simulator 17.0 on apple developer website.
but ive been try all solution but icant understand,

Comment: Did you resolve the issue? How did you make it work? My iPhone 15 Pro simulator just displays a black screen while the xcode project window continues to show "Installiing WeSplit (the name of the project) to iPhone 15 Pro" for a LONG TIME without any other progress information.